# Como faço para passar um valor de um objeto com o itext

Tags: java, relatório, itext

Eu tenho o seguinte fragmento de código:

```
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate()); 

while(iteratorRow.hasNext()){
    Object valorCelulaRow = iteratorRow.next(); 

    if ( valorCelulaRow != null ) {
        Paragraph p = new paragraph(); 
        p.add ( valueCellRow.toString() ); 

        doc.Add( ( Element ) p ); // ERRO 1 ALTERNATIVA
        doc.Add( p ); //ERRO  -  2 ALTERNATIVA
    }
}
```

Eu procurei no guia do itext, mas não encontrei uma solução para este problema.

http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=12

http://itextpdf.com/book/examples.php

...

Comment: Qual o motivo de adicionar 2 vezes a variavel `p` ?

Comment: Olá David. Obrigado por responder. Conseguir resolver este problema. Agora o meu arquivo pdf está carregando em branco, mesmo trazendo resultados com o teste que eu fiz em modo debug. O código completo está aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32335038/how-to-insert-the-values-in-page-pdf-with-itext-pdf/32336441?noredirect=1#comment52547174_32336441

Comment: Na verdade dá erro ao abrir o arquivo. parece estar corrompido